# the uiImage view exceeds the boundary of the table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I set the imageView mode to "aspect fill " , the image exceeds the cell boundary and part of the image appear in the cell below the image cell

How to make the image view inside its cell only?

Note : I'm using custom cell

Comment: you may need to add this code 
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @engmahsa Perfect , it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to add this code

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```